# Python ADFS Authentification

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, openid, adfs

I have to protect my backend written in python/django.
So I want achieve something like that:

1. Client login into web app (react)
2. Send request to my backend with token in header
3. My django app validate token and if it is correct send response

How to do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADFS MSAL (Microsoft Authentication Library) for Python.

[MSAL for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-python-adfs-support)

[Implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/active-directory?view=azure-python)